# (Wicket) Change visibility during ajax response

Tags: java, wicket

I have a AjaxPagingNavigator. Basically on a certain condition, the list which the AjaxPagingNavigator pages is reloaded. When this happens I only want to render the navigator when the list contains more than 1 page.

So does anyone know where I can attach a handler so that I can check for a visibility condition in my AjaxPagingNavigator and enable/disable visibility so that when the navigator is updated via. ajax it is either visible or not?

Markup:

```
<div wicket:id="mainWrap">
    <div wicket:id="navigator"/>
    <div wicket:id="listWrap">
        <div wicket:id="list><!-- here be content --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have an ajax event which refreshes "mainWrap" which refreshes the "navigator" along with the "list" and wrappings.

this is the event that triggers the whole thing.

```
 protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
     List foo = null; // do work to get list
     model.setFound(found); // update the model (thus updating "list")
     target.addComponent(mainWrap);
}
```

Edit: I know I can write

```
navigator.setVisibility(list.getPageCount() > 1);
```

after creating the navigator and after updating the model, but I was hoping to encapsulate that in a subclass of AjaxPagingNavigator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Be careful with doing expensive computations in an overridden `isVisible` method, as Wicket will call `isVisible` multiple times per request—not counting any calls you might inadvertently do.

Typically the best way to go about this is to override `onConfigure` and set the visibility flag manually.

```
@Override
void onConfigure() {
    super.onConfigure();
    setVisible(isVisible() && someExpensiveToCalculateCondition);
}
```

`onConfigure` is called just once during request processing, and called for all components, including those that are invisible (while `onBeforeRender` is only called for visible components).

Comment: I very much like this answer. Thanks for resurrecting this issue so much in the future :)

Comment: +1 - This one was a lifesaver (deserves two votes up :). But why calling "isVisible" on "onConfigure"? Using Dmitriy's example, if the first ajax returns "false" for "someExpensiveToCalculateCondition" and a second returns "true", I believe the "isVisible" will false the entire expression.

Comment: Eduardo, this one obviously depends on the usecase. One usually calls isVisible() to respect visibility changes somewhere up the onConfigure chain.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I touched Wicket, but if memory serves:

Can you not override the isVisible() method of your "navigator" object, such that it only displays under the condition you desire?

e.g. something like

```
.addComponent(new AjaxPagingNavigator(...) {
  @Override public boolean isVisible() { 
    return model.getFound().size() > 25;
  }
});
```

Comment: Ha! I feel so stupid. Here I looking through all sorts of crazy behaviors to attach and set visibility. Oy!

BTW "return super.isVisible() && this.getPageable().getPageCount() > 1;" is probably better since we want to ensure if someone else sets us to invisible we respect it.

Comment: Don't feel stupid... when I was developing Wicket applications I usually spent a lot of time looking for solutions to my various problems, and when I found them they were almost always much simpler than I expected.

Comment: I'll second that. I think the Wicket developers have done a great job, because usually as I look into an issue I realize how easy it was to solve/fix and more intuitive that I would have thought.

Comment: Should always setVisible in onConfigure(), for the reasons that are laid out in the answer.

Comment: Indeed. As @Sarhanis mentions, overriding `isVisible` is [not recommended](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/11/implement-wicket-component-visibility-changes-properly/) by the Wicket gurus. Instead, override `onConfigure` and control visibility from there.